# OnOpen or time trigger - move rows to another spreadsheet if 2 criteria met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have very little experience, in fact near none so some of my terminology is just recently 'herd' not known.

I have two Spreadsheets with 1 sheet named the same in each.

Spreadsheet "Production" with sheet "Master" - Sheet ID is  1goG0TS1_2jwlGRetREYNRVk-Q6TEy3iWG_5VXFoZlus

Spreadsheet "Archived_Production" "Master" - Sheet ID is  1Mr4LJmp1SmpDs1i8U_PE5uLOEVjLc599Vq87m9HwCx0

With an onOpen script, or maybe timed trigger,  set in my "Production" spreadsheet I need to MOVE all rows to my "Archived_Production" spreadsheet that meet 2 criteria

Criteria 1 - the Date in Column B is 7 days older than the current date

BUT ONLY IF, also

Criteria 2 - the entry in Column O is "100%"

In the included screenshot example, given today's date is 11/19/14, only the first entry highlighted in yellow would get moved upon next opening of the spreadsheet.

Thank you, as always, in advance for any help.

Sorry, not enough postings yet to allow image upload, but hopefully text explains.

Comment: You should look at the onEdit trigger that will copy the data to another sheet as soon as the cell value is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to perform the operation as you want on `onOpen()` script.

```
function onOpen() {
  // I moved data from sheet1 to sheet2

  var production_sheet_id = 'Put your production sheet's id here';  // This is your source sheet
  var archived_sheet_id = 'Put your archived sheet's id here';   // This is your destination sheet
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(production_sheet_id).getSheets()[0];
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(archived_sheet_id).getSheets()[0];

  var rows = sheet1.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var oldDate = values[i][1];     // or var oldDate =  new Date('values[i][1]')
    var curDate = new Date();

    // Count time difference in milliseconds, convert them into days then.
    var diffInMilliSecs = (curDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime());
    var diffInDays = diffInMilliSecs/1000/60/60/24;
    var diffInDays = Math.round(diffInDays);

    if(values[i][14] == 1.0 && Math.abs(diffInDays+30) >= 7)  // It evaluates 100% to 1.0
      sheet2.appendRow(values[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tweaked just a bit by robbing from other contributors on other aspects of this project. I only changed how the var for sheet1 and sheet2 are called; however this is not working. I am getting in script editor that "TypeError: Cannot find function getTime in object . (line 20, file "Code")". Not sure what I am missing, but this is checking cell O for the text of 100%, right? That is what I am trying to check in 2nd criteria.

Comment: Because I guess you might have used date as a string in your spreadsheet, while `getTime()` only works with Date object. You can see in my code, `oldDate` and `curDate`, both are `Date()` objects. values[i][1] contains the date but it is not the string, it's a date object too.

Comment: Sorry, I am so ignorant here. Yes, I am using Date format in column B of "Wed, NOV 19". What exactly do I need to change to make it work and what in the script is verifying the text of "100%" in column O? Sorry, I am totally useless at scripting, as you can tell

Comment: It's ok. Try to enter the Date into your spreadsheet in this format `MM/DD/YYYY`. For an instance, 12/19/2014. You are good to go then. And, I have made one changes in my code. My bad. Just chagne '-' sign to '+'. in script values[i][14] (it is 'o' column) is containing the '%' like 100%, 90% etc. When you evaluate a row, it will be evaluated as 100% -> 1.0, 90% -> 0.9 etc.

Comment: Thanks for that, I made 'sign' change and temporarily altered my date format to test. Still not moving the rows. I need to get it working, but I need my 'Thu, Nov 19' format to meet my needs. Just let me know if that is not even possible and I'll leave you alone and look for some other solutions. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: also, I tested by not using as onOpen, but linked to an image as a custom function name. When I fire it off I get same error as first mentioned in script editor about "getTime"

Comment: Well, I don't understand why is it not working for you? This code is pretty straight forward, and it's working for `onOpen() function` or `onOpen trigger` or custom function as you mentioned. Would you mind sharing the public link of your spreadsheet here? And, regarding the `Thu Nov 19` format, this is not a date object in GAS, it's a string. So, you will have to parse this string, and convert into `MM/DD/YYYY` format, which will be overhead at least to me.

Comment: Yes, I can share. These are both dummy test data, so no fears. Production data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1goG0TS1_2jwlGRetREYNRVk-Q6TEy3iWG_5VXFoZlus/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is the Archive_ sheet I am wanting to MOVE rows too.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mr4LJmp1SmpDs1i8U_PE5uLOEVjLc599Vq87m9HwCx0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, you should have changed the code according to your requirement, as my code moves data from one sheet to other sheet in the same spreadsheet, but you are trying to move from one spreadsheet to other spreadsheet. I have changed the first four lines of code for you which moves the data from one spreadsheet to other spreadsheet.

Comment: Regarding your getTime() error , your sheet is using the format which is not counted as date object as I have already told you before, you will have to use the format like MM/DD/YYYY. Or if you want to use the same format as you are using right now, you will have to implement the function for parsing your current format into the format MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: Thank you so much, as I had said I am ignorant with scripting, so changing the code didn't even seem obvious to me. THanks again.

Comment: I have went ahead and marked your answer as best answer, but even with changing my date format to mm/dd/yyyy the script doesn't take action and gives the same getTime function error. I am sure it is something I am doing wrong, but all I did was set my sheet ID's as you had specified in the first two variables. I'll just have to figure out on my own how to make it work. I do appreciate your past help and patience.

Comment: A contributor on another post suggested changing the var oldDate to this...... var oldDate = new Date(values[i][1]);  and it now works. Thanks for you help, wasn't sure if you wanted to edit your answer for that or not.

Comment: It should work without that too, but I will update it for you. Thanks